# Batch file for Add Network Location

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, network-programming

Hey I was wondering what the syntax for a batch file to add network location would be?

I know to map a drive you use the:

```
net use <drive letter><network path>
```

Is it possible to add a network location using batch file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried it? What were the results? Have you read the docs for that command?

Comment: If I just use: net use <network path> it says completed successfully but doesn't show as a location in my computer. I don't want to have to have a drive letter, or I would use the line in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't end up finding how to map with out a drive letter so I used the following:

```
net use * <network path>
```

The * will map to the highest available drive.